# Nginx php-fpm site slow

Tags: php, nginx, server

i have site on ubuntu, nginx with php-fpm,
My problem is that my first byte took about 15 seconds to respond.

below is the result of htop & www.conf file.

[image: Htop result is here]

[image: www.conf settings]

Comment: Based on you TOP. mysql is up to something. Try accessing a php-script without db-connection to isolate the problem. It's probably neither nginx nor fpm that's the problem. Hint: Add localhost to your /etc/hosts

Comment: @Teson i have placed a simple file & run, same issue, it took 25 sec to just print "hello world"
Now the TOP return 0.7% usage of mysql.

Comment: The problem is in what nginx is talking to, not in nginx itself. That also means all the relevant details aren’t in the question. Why is this question now tagged with both apache and nginx - which is it?

Comment: Also [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: what details you need more.

Comment: @chhameed, Do you have php-cli installed? Try to run a simple test php-script from the terminal. It will output any problems when loading extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable slow log for php-fpm to check which part in your code is slow.
Please check https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/fpm-slow-log/